# Why can not read url?

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-opengraph

That's the results from passing URL http://www.gatsby.com.tw/dance/4th_event/index.html to Debug Tool

Errors That Must Be Fixed:

> 無法讀取網站：    無法讀取這個頁面 http://www.gatsby.com.tw/dance/4th_event/index.html 。
>   Missing Required Property： The og:url property is required, but not present.
>   Missing Required Property： The og:type property is required, but not present.
>   Missing Required Property： The og:title property is required, but not present.

How do I check where is the error? Why linter can't read the page?

Comment: The server at www.gatsby.com.tw can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be working fine.

Please describe in more detail your issue as :

http://www.gatsby.com.tw/dance/4th_event/index.html

returns
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS records are not available all over the world; I suspect that they cannot be read in the USA. You should ask your ISP or domain provider to look into it.